# Multiple householdId's among units controllable from one Sonos mobile app?

Tags: sonos

I have 3 Sonos units controllable from my Sonos Android app: A, B, and C.
A and B return one householdId from `http://<ip>:1400/info`, but C returns a different householdId.

From the Sonos Android app (slightly abridged):

```
About My Sonos System

Controller
Version: 10.2 (build 50165071)

Sonos A
Play:1
Version: 10.2 (build 50165071)
Hardware Version: 1.20.1.601
Series Id: A200

Sonos B
Play:1
Version: 10.2 (build 50165071)
Hardware Version: 1.20.1.601
Series Id: A200

Sonos C
Play:1
Version: 10.2 (build 50165071)
Hardware Version: 1.20.1.601
Series Id: A200
```

Below are the two household IDs I observed.  Of note, the strings only differ after the '.'

`Sonos_K9Coj5AnNdwkpeGiArYtMHF4ug.6M_0OEa8aOhO-j2oZUMF`
`Sonos_K9Coj5AnNdwkpeGiArYtMHF4ug.WOnnBPGSlfiyINzEybJL`

```
$ curl http://192.168.5.33:1400/info && echo && curl http://192.168.9.42:1400/info && echo && curl http://192.168.5.71:1400/info && echo
{"websocketUrl":"wss:\/\/192.168.5.33:1443\/websocket\/api","playerId":"RINCON_7828CA92D6B201400","householdId":"Sonos_K9Coj5AnNdwkpeGiArYtMHF4ug.6M_0OEa8aOhO-j2oZUMF","groupId":"RINCON_7828CA92D6B201400:2486844229","apiVersion":"1.12.2","minApiVersion":"1.1.0"}
{"websocketUrl":"wss:\/\/192.168.9.42:1443\/websocket\/api","playerId":"RINCON_949F3E8AE0D601400","householdId":"Sonos_K9Coj5AnNdwkpeGiArYtMHF4ug.WOnnBPGSlfiyINzEybJL","groupId":"RINCON_949F3E8AE0D601400:1922741597","apiVersion":"1.12.2","minApiVersion":"1.1.0"}
{"websocketUrl":"wss:\/\/192.168.5.71:1443\/websocket\/api","playerId":"RINCON_7828CA92D67801400","householdId":"Sonos_K9Coj5AnNdwkpeGiArYtMHF4ug.WOnnBPGSlfiyINzEybJL","groupId":"RINCON_7828CA92D67801400:3241438112","apiVersion":"1.12.2","minApiVersion":"1.1.0"}
```

I expect all of these units to be in the same household, and thus have the same household ID, since they are all controllable from my Sonos Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player C may be joined to a different network. From the [Control](https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/control/) documentation:

> Each household is represented by a `householdId`. The `householdId` is stable with one exception. The value will change if players are moved to a different network. For example, if a user moves some players from a household to a different network, the players that were moved will use a different `householdId`. If all of the players in a household are moved to a different network, the `householdId` will remain the same.

Turn off the router that Player C is connected to and join it to the same network as the others. See [Connecting Sonos to a new router or WiFi network](https://support.sonos.com/s/article/1061?language=en_US) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they all have the same household id at the Player level (which is the part before the period), but the Cloud API thinks you have two households.

Sadly Sonos don't offer any kind of account-admin page that lets you see which apps are registered for their API, as then you could delete your account there and re-add it.

Something else to try: create a new API secret/key and login to that one with the same Sonos account, to see if the duplicate data occurs then.

Comment: Thanks for responding @ControlAV!  I have a few follow-ups.  How do you know that the household id before the period is 'Player level' vs. 'Cloud API level' for the whole thing?  Would you mind linking the docs that go over that?  I wasn't able to find those docs.  Also, I'm confused what you're referring to with the API secret/key stuff.  AFAICT, I wasn't using any API secret/key to make requests to the <ip>:1400/info endpoint since I was just doing basic curl commands.

Comment: I have never seen any documentation for hhids. From empirical evidence, the cloud APIs hhids are the LAN hhids plus a period plus a unique string.

You listed two Sonos_K9-hhids which are in cloud format, I assumed you obtained those through the documented authentication API, which required you to set up a secret/key pair on the developer site. I am not aware of any other method to get them.

Comment: Oh now I see: the /info page returns a cloud format hhid, huh, I never realized that before. I need to see how that relates to the ones that the cloud api returns.